# How R2DBC Statement.fetchsize exaclty works

Tags: postgresql, reactive, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I am using the [r2dbc-postgresql](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql) driver. Let's say we have a table with 1000 records and the `fetchSize` is 100:

```
connectionMono.flatMapMany(
                connection -> connection
                        .createStatement("select age from users")
                        .fetchSize(100)
                        .execute())
```

How many network calls will be executed? I know that using JDBC `Statement.SetFetchsize`, driver will fetch all rows in 10 batches of 100 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in the r2dbc driver, the behaviour is the same: it fetches rows by chunk with the specified size, so 100 in your case.

Here is the code of the method handling that in [ExtendedQueryMessageFlow](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/main/src/main/java/io/r2dbc/postgresql/client/ExtendedQueryMessageFlow.java):

```java
    /**
     * Execute the query and indicate to fetch rows in chunks with the {@link Execute} message.
     *
     * @param bindFlow  the initial bind flow
     * @param client    client to use
     * @param portal    the portal
     * @param fetchSize fetch size per roundtrip
     * @return the resulting message stream
     */
    private static Flux<BackendMessage> fetchCursored(Flux<FrontendMessage> bindFlow, Client client, String portal, int fetchSize) {

        DirectProcessor<FrontendMessage> requestsProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();
        FluxSink<FrontendMessage> requestsSink = requestsProcessor.sink();
        AtomicBoolean isCanceled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        return client.exchange(bindFlow.concatWithValues(new CompositeFrontendMessage(new Execute(portal, fetchSize), Flush.INSTANCE)).concatWith(requestsProcessor))
            .handle((BackendMessage message, SynchronousSink<BackendMessage> sink) -> {
                if (message instanceof CommandComplete) {
                    requestsSink.next(new Close(portal, PORTAL));
                    requestsSink.next(Sync.INSTANCE);
                    requestsSink.complete();
                    sink.next(message);
                } else if (message instanceof ErrorResponse) {
                    requestsSink.next(Sync.INSTANCE);
                    requestsSink.complete();
                    sink.next(message);
                } else if (message instanceof PortalSuspended) {
                    if (isCanceled.get()) {
                        requestsSink.next(new Close(portal, PORTAL));
                        requestsSink.next(Sync.INSTANCE);
                        requestsSink.complete();
                    } else {
                        requestsSink.next(new Execute(portal, fetchSize));
                        requestsSink.next(Flush.INSTANCE);
                    }
                } else {
                    sink.next(message);
                }
            })
            .as(flux -> Operators.discardOnCancel(flux, () -> isCanceled.set(true)));
    }
```